# Can't retrieve new value from GridView template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I am having trouble retrieving the new value that is entered in a textbox template field in my GridView.

Here is my markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And here is how I'm trying to retrieve the new value, inside the RowCommand event handler of my GridView:

```
 string userName = ((TextBox)grdUserList.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtUserName")).Text;
```

I get the old value instead of the newly typed value when I execute this code.

Does anyone know what I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you bind the gridview?

Comment: @Adil Hi. I just found out the solution for my problem. I searched and found out that the GridView is being refreshed before the retrieving process begins because I was rebinding the GridView on the Page_Load method. I fixed the problem by not rebinding the gridview when it is a post back (or at least not before I have made the changes). Thanks for your reply anyway :)

Comment: I was thinking that you are binding the GridView on postback and loosing the newly entered value.

Comment: @Adil I was binding the gridview inside the Page_Load. I didn't know that the pageLoad is executed first before the RowCommand event of the GridView when the page posts back. So I think what was happening was the content of the gridview( which contains the new data) was overwritten by the original content from my database( when the Page_Load is executed) so when I tried to get the new data in the Row_Command handler, I got the original content. Please excuse my English :D

Answer (score 2):

I just found out the solution for my problem. I searched and found out that the GridView is being refreshed before the retrieving process begins because I was rebinding the GridView on the Page_Load method. I fixed the problem by not rebinding the gridview when it is a post back (or at least not before I have made the changes) using the IsPostback method. Thanks for everyone's reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving new value in wrong GridView event. You have to add `OnRowUpdating="grdUserList_RowUpdating"` event in your GridView control and then retrieve new TextBox value.

`OnRowUpdating` event in code-behind:

```
protected void grdUserList_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string userName = ((TextBox)grdUserList.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserName")).Text;

    // Write your update query and logic over here.
}
```

You can take a reference from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt) for additional knowledge.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code in gridview    

  <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SrNo">
    <EditItemTemplate>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtsrno" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SrNo") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>


    <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblsrno" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SrNo") %>'>
    </asp:Label>

    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
```